# Chrome extension-javascript not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I just started building chrome extension by looking at the google's [example here:](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

I did exactly the same as mentioned above. Though I can see whatever i write in the body of my popup.html, it seems no section of the popup.js is working. I guess javascript is not working for my chrome extension.

I believe I follwed the CSP of Google but still.
Thanks in anticiptaion.

POPUP.HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width:  75px;
        height: 75px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
     -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

POPUP.JS

```
var QUERY = 'Kittens';

var kittenGenerator = {
  /**
   * Flickr URL that will give us lots and lots of whatever we're looking for.
   *
   * See http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html for
   * details about the construction of this URL.
   *
   * @type {string}
   * @private
   */
  searchOnFlickr_: 'https://secure.flickr.com/services/rest/?' +
      'method=flickr.photos.search&' +
      'api_key=90485e931f687a9b9c2a66bf58a3861a&' +
      'text=' + encodeURIComponent(QUERY) + '&' +
      'safe_search=1&' +
      'content_type=1&' +
      'sort=interestingness-desc&' +
      'per_page=20',

  /**
   * Sends an XHR GET request to grab photos of lots and lots of kittens. The
   * XHR's 'onload' event is hooks up to the 'showPhotos_' method.
   *
   * @public
   */
  requestKittens: function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", this.kittensOnFlickr_, true);
    req.onload = this.showPhotos_.bind(this);
    req.send(null);
  },

  /**
   * Handle the 'onload' event of our kitten XHR request, generated in
   * 'requestKittens', by generating 'img' elements, and stuffing them into
   * the document for display.
   *
   * @param {ProgressEvent} e The XHR ProgressEvent.
   * @private
   */
  showPhotos_: function (e) {
    var kittens = e.target.responseXML.querySelectorAll('photo');
    for (var i = 0; i < kittens.length; i++) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.constructKittenURL_(kittens[i]);
      img.setAttribute('alt', kittens[i].getAttribute('title'));
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
  },

  /**
   * Given a photo, construct a URL using the method outlined at
   * http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urlKittenl
   *
   * @param {DOMElement} A kitten.
   * @return {string} The kitten's URL.
   * @private
   */
  constructKittenURL_: function (photo) {
    return "http://farm" + photo.getAttribute("farm") +
        ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.getAttribute("server") +
        "/" + photo.getAttribute("id") +
        "_" + photo.getAttribute("secret") +
        "_s.jpg";
  }
};

// Run our kitten generation script as soon as the document's DOM is ready.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  kittenGenerator.requestKittens();
});
```

MANIFEST.JSON

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "WikiConnect",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a 'browser action' with kittens.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://secure.flickr.com/"
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "notification.html","popup.html","popup.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you post your code, I can help you with fixing it.

Comment: @BeardFist, Thanks in advance man. A very basic problem but no clue.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, nice and simple solution

Change:

```
req.open("GET", this.kittensOnFlickr_, true);
```

To:

```
req.open("GET", this.searchOnFlickr_, true);
```